# i want to show fake user infomation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, repeat, faker

i want to show fake user infomation on screen, so i used faker.js.
I made fake users infomation, put it in suggestions state, and give the Story component
and then i was tying to show user info on screen using map function, but it couldn't be.

this is my code

```
import faker from "faker";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Story from "./Story";

const Stories = () => {
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    const suggestion = [...Array(20)].map((_, i) => ({
      ...faker.helpers.contextualCard(),
      id: i,
    }));
    setSuggestions(suggestion);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {suggestions.map((profile) => {
        <Story
          key={profile.id}
          img={profile.avatar}
          username={profile.username}
        />;
      })}
      {/* story */}
      {/* story */}
      {/* story */}
      {/* story */}
      {/* story */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stories;
```

```
import React from "react";

const Story = ({ img, username }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      hihi
      <img src={img} alt="" />
      <p>{username}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Story;
```

i checked user info at 'suggestion'. it's no problem.

my english is not good, so thanks for read my question.

Comment: What's happening instead? Is there an error? Does the rest of the story work?

Comment: Doesn't have any error in console.. but everything is okay. 
 just cannot showing  the map function.
i am following this insta clone coding 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6Xs2Ir40OI'
1:41:27... I can't move forward. ㅠ-ㅠ

Comment: I found this "Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery." that is the problem i think, right??

Comment: Ohhh, your map callback isn't returning anything.

Comment: What the.... ㅠㅠ, it's not a big deal... Thank you so much! and i love you

Answer (score 1):

As [@Emile Bergeron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron) stated in the comments, the `.map` function isn't returning the `Story` element as you're expecting.

```js
{suggestions.map((profile) => {
  <Story
    key={profile.id}
    img={profile.avatar}
    username={profile.username}
  />;
})}
```

Change that to:

```js
{suggestions.map((profile) => {
  return <Story
    key={profile.id}
    img={profile.avatar}
    username={profile.username}
  />;
})}
```

Or replace the arrow function brackets with parentheses (implicit returns):

```js
{suggestions.map((profile) => (
  <Story
    key={profile.id}
    img={profile.avatar}
    username={profile.username}
  />
))}
```